# How to hide the CVS related information on the Source files in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I want to hide the CVS related information which shows for the files on Eclipse.
I am using Ganymede.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get quite a bit of control here:

```
 Windows -> Preferences -> Team -> CVS -> Label Decorations
```

In Eclipse 3.6 there is a preference:

```
 Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Label Decorations
```

See [link text](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp)

Comment: Sorry I cannot see CVS under Team.

Comment: @PoleStar In the preferences? Or did you look in the team context menu?

Comment: I can see a version number and the CVS domain names beside each file.